# What can I use to filter my Db2 outputs in Windows?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm trying to filter the output of a db2 command in windows CMD with "findstr". If i do for example: dir | findstr "create" - it works as expected, but if I use a db2 command as: db2 get db cfg | findstr "LOG" it gives nothing.

How can I filter a db2 output in windows? thanks in advance-

Comment: Define "Windows", what version, what shell. `findstr` is the recommended tool in a regular Windows shell. I assume that LOG is present when you retrieve the DB CFG?

Comment: `db2 get db cfg` (without the database alias specification) returns expected output, if you have established a database connection in the same session previously. Have you really done it?

Comment: Hi thank you, yes db2 get db cfg brings the expected output, but I would like to use something like in UNIX with the "| grep" to filter the output, not only for that but for different Db2 commands, with long outputs, versions of windows is windows server 2008.

Comment: and yes LOG is present in the output.